# Pandas: Concat rolling statistics with orginal dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to add rolling max, min and mean to my dataframe. my dataset is about 2 million rows so using apply takes a lot of time. This code will give me rolling in very efficient way, however, my issue is how to concat these to original data set.
df is groupby object and out is dataframe. I am hoping to be able to do something like this : `out = pd.concat([df, d1, d2, d3, d4], 1)`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 3)), 
                     columns=['Group','Time','Value'])
df.sort_values(by='Time', inplace=True)

suffix = 'my_suffix'
windows = [7, 14, 28]
df = df.groupby('Group')

d1 = pd.concat([df.rolling(w).mean()\
                  .rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_' + str(w) + 'D_mean_' + suffix)\
               for w in windows] , 1)
d2 = pd.concat([df.rolling(w).std()\
                  .rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_' + str(w) + 'D_std_' + suffix) \
               for w in windows] , 1)
d3 = pd.concat([df.rolling(w).min()\
                  .rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_' + str(w) + 'D_min_' + suffix) \
               for w in windows] , 1)
d4 = pd.concat([df.rolling(w).max()\
                  .rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_' + str(w) + 'D_max_' + suffix) \
               for w in windows] , 1)

out = pd.concat([d1, d2, d3, d4], 1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
ori=df.copy()
pd.concat([ori.set_index('Group',append=True).swaplevel(0,1),out], 1).reset_index()
```